# Clean way to raise error on numpy array negative index?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, error-handling, indexoutofboundsexception

Numpy naturally treats negative array indices as counting from the end of the array. Is there any clean way of causing this to throw an `IndexError` (out of bounds) exception without overwriting `ndarray.__get__()`?

`ndarray`s have an [`ndarray.take()`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.take.html) function, and this would be a great place to incorporate such an option. In fact, you can get an error on negative indices when you use `mode='clip'`, but not in `mode='raise'`.

Of course I could always access the array through some wrapper that does this check, but I would like to know if there is some built-in solution.

Comment: Why don't you want to override anything? It seems a fairly simple matter to subclass `ndarray` and override `__getitem__()`, `__setitem__()`, and `__delitem__()` to reject negative indexes.

Comment: …for that matter, why do you want to reject negative indexes?